# Is it bad practice getting DOM elements multiple times in different functions?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some javascript code which counts the remaining characters in a textarea as the user types text in it.

```
window.onload = function () {
    captureTextArea();
    showRemainingCharacters();
}

function showRemainingCharacters() {
    let textareaBox = document.getElementById('postBody');

    let insertedCharacters = textareaBox.value.length;
    let counter = 1000 - insertedCharacters;
    let countRemaining = document.getElementById('charactersRemaining');
    countRemaining.innerHTML = "Characters left: " + counter;

}

function captureTextArea() {
    let textareaBox = document.getElementById('postBody');

    textareaBox.addEventListener('keyup', showRemainingCharacters, false);
    textareaBox.addEventListener('keydown', showRemainingCharacters, false);

}
```

Now, I learned why should avoid using the global scope for basically anything, however in the case of me needing to get a DOM element multiple times (in this case, twice) in 2 different functions, this being:

`let textareaBox = document.getElementById('postBody');`

I would like to know if this is bad practice and/or is there any other way of refactoring this code in order to avoid using the global scope so both functions can access this element.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm very new to Javascript and I have yet to work with classes and modules, I will however take a look at it to try to get a basic understanding of it.

Comment: It's fine to retrieve an element multiple time, especially by ID since this is a very fast lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see any errors for declaring a DOM element in the global scope. There is a simple rule, DRY, don't repeat your self. So I would do it like this here, especially when I know that I will use it on multiple places, and rename the element with a unique name to easily find them if needed. I think the code looks also cleaner in this way. This olso helps you later when you need to change the name or something, you only change it in one place.

```html
const postBodyTextArea = document.getElementById('postBody');

window.onload = function () {
    captureTextArea();
    showRemainingCharacters();
}

function showRemainingCharacters() {
   
    let insertedCharacters = postBodyTextArea.value.length;
    let counter = 1000 - insertedCharacters;
    let countRemaining = document.getElementById('charactersRemaining');
    countRemaining.innerHTML = "Characters left: " + counter;
    
}

function captureTextArea() {

    postBodyTextArea.addEventListener('keyup', showRemainingCharacters, false);
    postBodyTextArea.addEventListener('keydown', showRemainingCharacters, false);
    
}
```

Comment: I understand. However I would like to know if there's any specific guidelines on what to not use on the global scope, or in other words, is there any reason on why it's/is not okay to define variables that are DOM elements in the global scope?

Comment: Polluting global scope is generally frowned-upon, and I would personally prefer the evil of getting the element each time in the function (though there are better ways!).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with it but its better to only do it only once, you could make an IIFE module or use a class which on construct, sets up things for the functionality of that specific feature.

Something to also note is you might want multiple textareas on the page, if so you will then end up repeating code, so instead find the textareas once with a selector, then attach the functionality, also the limit and remaining text could be an option.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(elm => new textareaLimit(elm, {
    maxChars: elm.getAttribute('maxlength'),
    hideRemaining: elm.hasAttribute('data-hide-remaining') || false
  }))
}

class textareaLimit {
  constructor(elm, options = {}) {
    this.options = {
      maxChars: 1000,
      hideRemaining: false
    }
    if (options.maxChars) this.options.maxChars = parseInt(options.maxChars, 10)
    if (options.hideRemaining) this.options.hideRemaining = true

    this.elm = elm
    this.remainingCharacters()
    this.events()
  }
  remainingCharacters() {
    if (!this.options.hideRemaining && !this.charactersRemaining) {
      this.charactersRemaining = this.elm.parentNode.querySelector('span.charactersRemaining')
      if (!this.charactersRemaining) {
        this.charactersRemaining = document.createElement("span")
        this.charactersRemaining.className = 'charactersRemaining'
        this.elm.parentNode.appendChild(this.charactersRemaining)
      }
    }

    if (this.elm.value.length > this.options.maxChars) {
      this.elm.value = this.elm.value.substr(0, this.options.maxChars)
    }

    if (!this.options.hideRemaining) this.charactersRemaining.innerText = "Characters left: " + (this.options.maxChars - this.elm.value.length)
  }
  events() {
    this.elm.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.remainingCharacters(), false);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <textarea data-hide-remaining></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <textarea maxlength="10"></textarea>
</div>
```